# Is there a better way to delete an installer after installation, in chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

eg.

```
remote_file '/app/abc/' + '/app.rpm' do
    source "https://location.com/app.rpm"
end
package 'app.rpm' do
    source '/app/abc/app.rpm'
end
file '/app/abc/app.rpm' do
    action :delete
end
```

This is how I am currently deleting the rpm file. Is there a better way to write the code, without having to include the `file` resource again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We generally recommend not deleting so you can use the file for idempotence checks, using a notification to run the package install if the remote file changes.